# Titanium For Iphone app

Tags: iphone, titanium

I am very new to Titanium. I created one project just by clicking new project and then launched the same. It did not launch. Displayed Info was application exited from Simulator and warning was SDK not Supported. My Titanium version is 1.2.0. Can anyone help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: Text reads better if you put a space after punctuation like periods (`.`) and commas (`,`).

Comment: It'd better if you post log content when building. After read error in this log file, we'll easily know what wrong with your app.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you're trying to launch from a PC rather than a Mac. In order to create and run an iPhone app from Titanium (or any platform, for that matter) you must be using a Mac AND you must have the iPhone SDK installed AND you must point your installation of Titanium to where the SDK is installed.